# xcode ios Read Remote TXT File

Tags: ios, xcode

I developed an app and published it on Apple Store.
I have a config file with a parameter that sometimes I need to change it but I have to resend all the time the code and wait that apple approve it, so I thought to create a txt file on a remote server then let the app read it and set the parameter.
Example:

PARAMETER = VALUE

the Value is an INT, so it look like the following:

## define PARAMETER @1

I wanna a remote file for example on http://www.server.com/config.txt that it contain an int (in this case "1")

So:

1

## define PARAMETER @remoteconfigvalue

I wanna also to put an "ELSE" if the Phone is without connection so can't read the file.
How its possible to do it? Can please someone help me? Im new in this and I have no idea where to start.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: What have you tried? That is a pretty basic task: simply open the URL and interpret the contents or use the default if the connection fails.

Comment: Hello Luk, thanks for your reply. I really didnt tryed anything, I was looking on Google for something but I can't realize where to start, I'm really new on this.Thanks

Comment: Anyone? I really can't figure how to do it !!